# The Book Riemann's Zeta Function by Edwards - Possible Error in Section 1.17?

Tags: riemann-zeta

This question concerns the book *Riemann's Zeta Function*, H.M. Edwards (Dover, 1974).  On pages 25 to 36, Edwards provides a detailed proof of Riemann's explicit formula for the prime counting function.  I'll first show two key equations in that proof.

For $x > 1$, Edwards derives a formula for $J(x)$:
\begin{equation*} 
J(x) = \operatorname{li}(x) -\sum_{Im(\rho) > 0} \left[\operatorname{li}(x^{\rho}) + \operatorname{li}(x^{1-\rho})\right] + \int_x^{\infty}  \frac{dt}{t (t^2 - 1) \log t} -\log2,
\end{equation*}
where the last two terms of $J(x)$ are small and do not grow with $x$.

Let $\pi(x)$ be the prime counting function and $\mu(n)$ be the Möbius function. For any fixed $x \geq 2$ choose the smallest integer $N$ such that $x < 2^N$.  Edwards shows:
\begin{equation*} 
\pi(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} J(x^{1/n}).
%\quad\quad \text{ for } x < 2^N.\quad N = \min\LR{N\in\Nbb, x < 2^N}
\end{equation*}

Disregarding the last three terms of $J(x)$, we have
\begin{equation*} 
\pi(x) \sim \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \operatorname{li}(x^{1/n}),
\end{equation*}
which has proved to be a good approximation of $\pi(x)$.

Edwards then gives (page 35) the following formula for the error in the above approximation:
\begin{equation*} 
\pi(x) - \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \operatorname{li}(x^{1/n}) =  
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{Im(\rho)>0} \left[ \operatorname{li}(x^{\rho/n}) + \operatorname{li}(x^{(1-\rho)/n}) \right] + 
\text{ lesser terms}.
\end{equation*}

**Now to my question**.  Edwards error formula does not look correct to me.  Shouldn't the formula be
\begin{equation*} 
\pi(x) - \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \operatorname{li}(x^{1/n}) =  
-\sum_{n=1}^{N}  \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \sum_{Im(\rho)>0}  \left[ \operatorname{li}(x^{\rho/n}) + \operatorname{li}(x^{(1-\rho)/n}) \right] + \text{ lesser terms}.
\end{equation*}

As an aside, I searched the Internet for errata on the Edwards book and found nothing.  Is anyone aware of a listing of errata for his book?

**(Edit - Added an Example).**

Fix $x = 15 = 2^4 - 1$. Note that $\mu(1) = 1$, $\mu(2) = -1$, $\mu(3) = -1$ and $\mu(4) = 0$. Let
\begin{equation*}
S(n) = \sum_{Im(\rho)>0} \left[ \operatorname{li}(x^{\rho/n}) + \operatorname{li}(x^{(1-\rho)/n}) \right].
\end{equation*}
Using $x=15$, we now show the two formulae for the approximation error:
\begin{align*}
\pi(15) - \sum_{n=1}^{4} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \operatorname{li}(x^{1/n}) &= S(1) + S(2) + S(3) + S(4) 
+ \text{ lesser terms},\\
\pi(15) - \sum_{n=1}^{4} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \operatorname{li}(x^{1/n}) &= -S(1) + \frac{S(2)}{2} 
+ \frac{S(3)}{3} + \text{ lesser terms}.
\end{align*}
Edwards calls his expression ``an exact analytical formula for the error''.  That suggests
that either: (1) the two expressions above are equal (which seems unlikely), or (2) one of the two expressions is incorrect.

Comment: As $\sum \mu(n)/n=0$ not sure that term matters in any way

Comment: @Conrad That is true for an infinite sum.  But for any give x, we only have a partial sum (up to N).  Does that make a difference with respect to your comment?

Comment: The partial sums go to zero by the definition of limit

Comment: @Conrad The summation over $\rho$ has some dependence on $n$, so we can't ignore the whole thing without expanding it.

Comment: @Conrad I added an example to show you better how I am viewing this.  Perhaps I am missing some key point, in which case my example should help you see what I am missing.

Comment: I get your point as I looked in Edwards (am away so saw this on phone originally where long equations are scrambled) and I still think there is no serious issue since for $n=1$ the terms are equal in both formulas as $\mu(1)=1$ (not sure why you have $-S(1)$ in your second formula above as it still should be $S(1)$ as per Edwards page $35$) while the terms from $n=2$ on are smaller and at most order $Li(x^{1/4})$ so essentially only $S(1)$ matters anyway; I think that Edwards main point is that mysteriously $S(1)$ seems to have large cancellation so it actually doesn't matter after all

Comment: Conrad The $-S(1)$ comes from the minus sign before the second term in the first expression above of $J(x)$.  I include the same minus sign in my "correction" of Edwards.

Comment: I agree with what you say - I looked up Riemann original paper and the inversion formula is indeed the correct one there so I guess Edwards has indeed a typo but as noted it doesn't seem to be that relevant maybe except for the sign of $S(1)$ since the other terms are much less than the best error possible which we know to be square root on RH; the $S(1)$ term clearly encodes the equivalence between (at most) square root error and RH; the actual unconditional at least square root error came later from Littlewood and needed some extra work beyond Landau theorem as shown in Ingham for example

Comment: @Conrad If you put your comment into an answer, I'll upvote.